# How to differentiate a string from the value '0' when stored in a variable in php

Tags: php

I have the code:

```
if ($difference[$y] <> "Never") { 
      echo ' days';} 
?>
```

Basically the value of $difference[$y] is either a number between 0 & 9, or the string "never". I want to echo the string 'days' when the value of $difference[$y] is a number (0-9). It works for all numbers however when the number is 0, the string is not echo'd. How can i fix this?

Comment: Use identical operator. `!==`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [`is_numeric`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) for this. This function will return true if the value of the variable is numeric, even with strings.

Like so:

```
<?php
if (is_numeric($difference[$y]))
    echo ' days';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is having inbuilt function `is_numeric` to identify the value is numeric or not. You can use this function as like below example.

> reference: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

```
<?php
  $difference = array("nothing","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","everything","stringIts");

  for($y=0;$y<count($difference);$y++){
    echo (is_numeric($difference[$y]))?$d[$y]." days <br/>":"";
  }
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0 days 
1 days 
2 days 
3 days 
4 days 
5 days 
6 days 
7 days 
8 days 
9 days 
10 days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var = 10;
if ($var >=0 && $var<=9) { 
      echo ' days';
} 
?>
```

only display days when variable is between 0 and 9.